# How does Rust infer lifetime while raw pointers are involved?

Tags: rust, lifetime, unsafe, raw-pointer

```rust
struct MyCell<T> {
    value: T
}

impl<T> MyCell<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        MyCell { value }
    }
    
    fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }
    
    fn set(&self, new_value: T) {
        unsafe { 
            *(&self.value as *const T as *mut T) = new_value; 
        }
    }
}

fn set_to_local(cell: &MyCell<&i32>) {
    let local = 100;
    cell.set(&local);
}

fn main() {
    let cell = MyCell::new(&10);
    set_to_local(&cell);
}
```

When calling `cell.set(&local)`, suppose `cell` is `'x` and `'&local` is `'y`, I am told that the covariance rule will change the type of `cell` from `&MyCell<'x, &i32>` to `&MyCell<'y, &i32>`.

How does the assignment inside the unsafe block affect the lifetime inference for the parameters of `set()`? Raw pointers does not have lifetime then how does the compiler know it should make `cell` and `new_value` have the same lifetime using covariance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How does the assignment inside the unsafe block affect the lifetime inference for the parameters of `set()`?

It doesn't — and this is not even specific to raw pointers or `unsafe`. Function bodies *never* affect any aspect of the function signature (except for `async fn`s which are irrelevant here).

> Raw pointers does not have lifetime then how does the compiler know it should make `cell` and `new_value` have the same lifetime using covariance?

It sounds like you misread some advice. In the code you have, `Cell<T>` is invariant in `T`, but for an interior-mutable type to be sound, it must be **invariant** (not covariant) in the type parameter. In the code you have, the compiler infers covariance for `T` because `MyCell` contains a field that is simply of the type `T`. Covariance is the “typical” case for most generic types.

Therefore, **the code you have is unsound** because `MyCell` is covariant over `T` but must instead be invariant over `T`.

Your code is *also* unsound because in the implementation of `set()`, you're creating an immutable reference to a `T`, `&self.value`, and then writing to its referent. This is “undefined behavior” *no matter how you do it,* because creating `&self.value` asserts to the compiler/optimizer that the pointed-to memory won't be modified until the reference is dropped.

If you want to reimplement the standard library's `Cell`, you must do it like the standard library does, with the [`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) primitive:

```rust
pub struct Cell<T: ?Sized> {
    value: UnsafeCell<T>,
}
```

[`UnsafeCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.UnsafeCell.html) is how you opt out of `&`'s immutability guarantees: creating an `&UnsafeCell<T>` *doesn't* assert that the `T` won't be mutated. It is also invariant in `T`, which automatically makes the containing type invariant in `T`. Both of these are necessary here.

Comment: Thanks! One more question: when using ``Cell<T>``, ``set(&local)`` will cause lifetime mismatch compiling error because ``Cell`` is invariant to ``T`` and the compiler sees ``&cell`` and ``&local`` have different lifetimes. But the function signature of ``Cell<T>::set()`` doesn't require the two inputs should have the same lifetime, how does the compiler know it? Similarly, when using ``MyCell<T>``, when we call ``set()``, what are the lifetimes associated with the two inputs? Are they the same? If so, then why does the compiler require they should be the same?

Comment: @DizzyZeratul **The lifetime is part of `T`.** The function signature requires a value of type `T`, and in this case `T` is `&'_ i32` with some particular lifetime (not given any name in the source code). Within any specific call to `Cell::set()` it's *always the same lifetime* in the Cell type and in the argument — but variance then determines whether it's OK (covariance) or not (invariance) to coerce `&MyCell<&'long i32>` into `&MyCell<&'short i32>` for purposes of each call.